# Does a DDOS attack on an application using CDN have to first bring down all the involved CDN servers to affect the application's availability?

Tags: security, cdn, ddos, denial-of-service

CDN are said to absorb and mitigate the Denial of Service and DDOS attacks. Consider an application that uses a CDN provider to deliver its content. So if an attacker tries to bring down such an application using DOS or DDOS, the flood of requests made during such an attack will go to the CDN servers. Will such a DDOS attack have to completely bring down all the CDN servers serving this application's content before impairing the origin server completely?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for such questions

Comment: Thanks. Posted this question on security.stackexchange.com 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224069/does-a-ddos-attack-on-an-application-using-cdn-have-to-first-bring-down-all-the